# how to enforce that a java/spring boot project is following .editorconfig rules

Tags: java, editorconfig

I have configured editorconfig in intellij which is helping me in formatting the code as i require. Is there any way i can throw compile time errors when .editorconfig rules are not followed.

I went through some existing plugins they are fine but wondering if there is any formal way or universally accpeted way. It would be helpful if anyone can point be in right way.

Following plugin is close to my requirements.
[editorconfig-maven-plugin](https://ec4j.github.io/editorconfig-maven-plugin/)

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ, so no idea how to enforce the rules there. I'd just have the linter run in a pre-commit hook. Check the pre-commit framework.